Black canvas output from jsfeat
I am trying to test drive jsfeat.js but only see a black canvas output. What am I doing wrong?
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            border: solid 1px red;
            width: 20vw;
        }

        canvas {
            border: solid 1px blue;
            width: 80vw;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsfeat/0.0.8/jsfeat-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src='http://localhost/.../images/test-image.jpg'>

<script>
    function processImage(canvas, img, radius, low_threshold, high_threshold) {
        let w=img.naturalWidth;
        let h=img.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        let img_u8 = new jsfeat.matrix_t(w, h, jsfeat.U8_t | jsfeat.C1_t);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

        jsfeat.imgproc.grayscale(imageData.data, w, h, img_u8);

        // render result back to canvas
        var data_u32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
        var alpha = (0xff << 24);
        var i = img_u8.cols*img_u8.rows, pix = 0;
        while(--i >= 0) {
            pix = img_u8.data[i];
            data_u32[i] = alpha | (pix << 16) | (pix << 8) | pix;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    }
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    const img = document.querySelector('img');

    let radius=3;
    let low_threshold=127;
    let high_threshold=127;

    if (img.complete) {
        console.log('img already loaded');
        processImage(canvas, img,radius, low_threshold, high_threshold);
    }
    else {
        img.onload = function () {
            console.log('img loaded');
            processImage(canvas, img,radius, low_threshold, high_threshold);
        };

        img.onerror = function () {
            console.error('Failed to load the image.');
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


You need to draw the img into canvas before processing the image data, as ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h) is trying to get the image data from the canvas, which is empty at this stage in your script.
function processImage(canvas, img, radius, low_threshold, high_threshold) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);

        let img_u8 = new jsfeat.matrix_t(canvas.width, canvas.height, jsfeat.U8_t | jsfeat.C1_t);
        let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        jsfeat.imgproc.grayscale(imageData.data, canvas.width, canvas.height, img_u8);

        // render result back to canvas
        var data_u32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
        var alpha = (0xff << 24);
        var i = img_u8.cols*img_u8.rows, pix = 0;
        while(--i >= 0) {
            pix = img_u8.data[i];
            data_u32[i] = alpha | (pix << 16) | (pix << 8) | pix;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

